# How to match to node of ansestor that is not named X by passing known element id

Tags: html, xpath

Hoping someone can help. I am trying to read the text value of a label that is associated with the selected radio button.

I can see which option is already selected by searching for the radio button who's checked value is set as 'True'. Once I have located this element, I want to work backwards to get the text of the tag 'label'.

I have tried to use the following xPath command to get all ancestor nodes that are not div, but this searches from the root of my node tree, not from the id (js_9a4).

```html
//*[not(ancestor::label)]
//*input:radio[@aria-checked="True"][not(ancestor::div])]
```

[image]

Could someone farmiliar with xPath help me here?

Comment: You cannot use DOM? `checkboxElement.closest('label').firstChild.textContent`

Comment: Are `div` elements permitted children of a `label`?

Comment: @mplungjan I will take a look at DOM now, but i was hoping to learn how to do this using xPath as I am currently learning ZennoPoster, and it would provide a more solid method for future tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to going back up the tree is that you can test (in a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates)) for a descendant element with the specified id...

```xml
//label[.//*[@id='js_9a4']]/text()
```

That selects the text node. If you want the `label` element itself, remove the `/text()`.

Comment: Just out of interest, how would one, then get the innertext value of the last child of the node we have just found?

Comment: @MadDire - if I’m reading that correctly you’d replace `text()` with `*[last()]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

This should indeed be possible with the ancestor tag but you are using it wrong.
You need to start at the radio button node and from there search for an ancestor label. Following xPath should work for you:

```
//*[@id="js_9a4"]/ancestor::label
```